# PHP using _GET, Switch, and Heredoc

Tags: php, get, switch-statement, heredoc

I'm a noob in a web scripting course. The prof wanted us to take the HTML pages we built and start getting things converted to PHP. He wanted to see some dynamic changes to a "Level 2" web page and asked that we use things such as _GET and Switch or If/Then.  My plan: pass parameters in my navigation links to a single page that dynamically changes content using Switch based on the link that was clicked.

**I'm not sure how to properly access the key/values in the destination file.**  Every example I see shows a sentence that echos the key/value (example: **echo "Study " . $_GET['subject'] . " at " . $_GET['web']**); but that's not what I need to do; I need to **use** but not display the key/value to help Switch statements figure out what HTML block of code to display.  (Based on advice I've seen on SO, I'm using Heredoc to insert blocks of HTML in PHP code.)

Sample of Navigation links code (where I'm passing the key/values):

```
<li><a href="level2Site.php?subject=Scorecard">Scorecard Process</a></li>
<li><a href="level2Site.php?subject=Scoping">Scoping Process</a></li>
```

Sample of destination file "level2Site":

```
<?php
switch($subject){
    case "Scorecard":
        //For Scorecard process webpage. HEREDOC, i.e., "<<<", used to allow a chunk of HTML code to be run within PHP code.
        echo <<<END_OF_TEXT
            <div class="main">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Scorecard Process</h3>
                    <p>
                    All incoming projects...                        
                    <br><br>
                    <em><a href="Scorecard.docx">Link to Scorecard</a></em>
                    <br><br>
                    <em><strong>Sample Scorecard (Blank):</strong></em>
                    </p>
                    <br><br>
            </div>
        END_OF_TEXT;                    
        break;

    case "Scoping":
        //For Scoping process webpage 
        echo <<<END_OF_TEXT2
            <h3>Scoping Process</h3>.......etc.
```

I don't know where to put the _GET code or how it should be written?  Not sure how to combine it with the Heredoc syntax?

Thank you.

Comment: Before your `switch` you'd need something like `$subject = $_GET['subject'] ?? "some default value";`

Comment: @Phil, that fixed it.  You have no idea how much time I spent on this...super grateful!